# How do I make Barrier run on startup?

Tags: raspbian, connection, keyboard, mouse

So every time I start up my Raspberry Pi I have to unplug my mouse from my main PC into my Raspberry Pi 4 and manually open up barrier so that I don't have to use 2 set of KB&M but I want to cut this step out entirely. How would I be able to do so?

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn't already exist, create an autostart directory, e.g. `mkdir ~/.config/autostart`

Copy the .desktop file from `/usr/share/applications`, e.g. `cp /usr/share/applications/barrier.desktop ~/.config/autostart`

Check the config file has the correct setup, in my case it was here: `~/.config/Debauchee/Barrier.conf`

Reboot pi and wait a few seconds for barrier to start.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a KVM switch? You can get [a KVM switch that supports VGA](https://www.walmart.com/c/kp/kvm-switches) for very little money; the [ones that support HDMI](https://www.walmart.com/c/kp/hdmi-kvm-2-ports) (so you can also share a monitor) are a bit more expensive, but not too bad. Be sure to check the specifications carefully as these things can vary quite a lot.

Otherwise, have you tried `cron` for starting `barrier` at startup?

```bsh
edit crontab -e
```

When editor opens, add a line similar to this (see `man crontab` or post questions here:

```
@reboot /path/to/barrier
```

Comment: A physical KVM isn't always appropriate, and just being able to just scoot your mouse to a second screen is *far* more immediate and convenient than having to reach over and press a button on a box, or remember which arcane hot-key combination this particular kvm uses.
This answer would be better if it answered the question first, and then offered the [frame challenge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263672/138432) afterwards, rather than suggesting people shouldn't be trying to do what they want to do, and then grudgingly answering the question afterwards.